# Removing YourSelf from the ShareActionProvider list

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I'm using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) in an app along with a ShareActionProvider. I'm using a share intent to share images in a manner very similar to the [ActionBarSherlock example](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ShareActionProviders.java):

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

Everything is working properly, the only problem is that my app also accepts shared image content ("image/*"), so it shows up in the list of apps. Is there anyway around this?

**EDIT:**

Here are my intent filters:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Can you post your intent filters?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I have posted them.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you want to do, basically, you want to enable/disable your intent-filters dynamically.

Up to where I know you can't achieve what you want directly, but you can get the same effect disabling your activity, via [PackageManager and setComponentEnabledSetting()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting). Obviously, 
if disabling the "receiver" Activity is a possibility in your app.